# Which Stack Exchange site should I post this question about website hosting / design to?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm curious about which Stack Exchange site to ask some questions about how to design the hosting for a website. I'd need the site to do:

1. Usual blogging stuff - text, code snippets from GitHub, etc.
2. Host a database
3. Run cron jobs (in R / Python) to update data
4. Serve pages (HTML? maybe) that contain data generated from the database and R, Python, and SQL jobs.

I've looked at [Amazon AWS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services), and it seems pricey, but I'm not sure if something like WordPress has enough resources to pull this off. Any suggestions on where to post this would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think any site would accept it; at the level You're describing it sounds too broad, and falls into the "help me shop" category. The only one which might take it is Software Recommendations, but you'd be well advised to study their help center first.